# How app can obtain openvpn server cert on the client?

Tags: openvpn

openvpn client can connect to the server and is live. The task is for the app installed on client machine to get the server certificate used during negotiations and monitor its expiration.

I found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029181/openvpn-vpn-server-certificate-retrieval) but get `connect:errno=111`. I suspect the problem is openvpn server using udp uinstead of tcp, but I can't find another way.

May it be openvpn client stores/caches the server certificate somewhere after connecting?
Can you please advise what is the best way to get server's cert on the client?